# Where does the truncus get its name from? What is it cutting?

Tags: functions, terminology

I have gathered that the name truncus is related to truncated (from the Latin), but I'm unsure in what sense a truncus ($ \frac{1}{x^2} $ or more generally $\frac{a}{(x-b)^2}+c$) is cutting anything. I wonder whether there is some analogy to parabolas being considered as conic sections, but my research isn't yielding any leads.

Comment: It's not directly related, but rather winding. The function is named because it looks like [this thing](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncus_arteriosus).

Comment: It's actually the same word as *trunk*, as in tree trunk.